# Integration of root of a squared term

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Consider the following indefinite integral :

\begin{align} \int{{(1 + 2 \tan x(\tan x + \sec x)})^{1/2} dx} \end{align}
Clearly after simplifying the expression it would become :
\begin{align} \int{\sqrt{(\sec x + \tan x)^2} dx} \end{align}
And we know that
\begin{align} \sqrt{x^2} = |x| \end{align}
So, we can't directly write it as **sec x + tan x** (It can also be **-(sec x + tan x)** but I have seen in my book that the author just wrote it as like that and integrated it.
Why is it so?

Comment: There is something wrong with your simplification, or a typo in your LaTeX. For $x=\pi/4$, $\sec x=\sqrt2$ and $\tan x=1$, so the integrand is $1+2\sqrt{1+\sqrt2}$ in the former, and $1+\sqrt2$ in the latter (and the values are obviously different).

Comment: I have corrected it.

Comment: Ok. Regarding integrating $\sec(x)+\tan(x)$ when the integrand is $|\sec(x)+\tan(x)|$, it's obviously wrong, but it's the kind of abuse I have sometimes seen. Although I would expect rather something like $\pm\int\sec(x)+\tan(x)\,\mathrm dx$: the sign of $\sec(x)+\tan(x)$ is constant on intervals $(\pi/2+k\pi,\pi/2+(k+1)\pi)$, so getting rid of the absolute value is correct (up to a factor $\pm1$) on each such interval.

Comment: And since the function has poles at $\pi/2+k\pi$ anyway, it doesn't hurt very much. It's different with $|\sin x|$, which is a continuous function: it has a continuous primitive on $\Bbb R$, and it's not $\int\sin x\,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: Why sign of sec(x)+tan(x) is constant on intervals (π/2+kπ,π/2+(k+1)π)?

Comment: Because $\sec x+\tan x=\frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}$ and the numerator is $\ge0$, hence it has the same sign as $\cos x$, and $\cos x$ has roots at $\pi/2+k\pi$.

Comment: But cos x is changing it's sign continuously then why are we just taking +ve ?

Comment: That's what I wrote: cosine changes sign at $\pi/2+k\pi$, hence on intervals $(\pi/2+k\pi,\pi/2+(k+1)\pi)$, you can remove the absolute value and put a factor $+1$ or $-1$ before the integral.